# What is the benefit of using `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` for creating/managing policy for AWS Secrets manager?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

In Terraform `aws` provider, we can use the below to attach a Resource based policy to the secrets manager.

- Create a `aws_iam_policy_document` Data resource and attach the same to the secrets manger
- Create policy using `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` for a secrets manager.

I remember the older versions of the provider for e.g 2.7 did not had `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` and we had to use the data resource to attach policy to the secrets manager. Now the latest version supports both.

What is the benefit of using the `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` over `aws_iam_policy_document` and under what conditions we can choose one over the other ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your actual question is about setting the `policy` attribute on the `aws_secretsmanager_secret` resource, versus creating the policy as a separate `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` resource.

The main reason you would use `aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` instead of setting it directly on the secret resource, is if the secret was created in different Terraform code, or perhaps completely outside of Terraform. For example if you wanted to create a Terraform template to look up all your AWS secrets, and set a policy on all of them.

You can use `aws_iam_policy_document` with either of these. `aws_iam_policy_document` is just a way to define IAM policies in Terraform code instead of embedded raw JSON strings.

Answer (score 1):

`aws_secretsmanager_secret_policy` is to create a [resource-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html), whereas `aws_iam_policy_document` is for [identity-based policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html). There is a number of differences between them as explained in [Identity-based policies and resource-based policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_identity-vs-resource.html).

The most common scenario where you would use a `resource-based policy`  is for [cross-account access to your secret](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-access-secrets-across-aws-accounts-by-attaching-resource-based-policies/).

Comment: Hi @Marcin , Thanks for the response. we can create Resource based policies using `aws_iam_policy_document` . As I mentioned in my question, you can use datasource resource of type aws_iam_policy_document and then attach this as policy to the secrets manager. You can add the a statement to allow cross account statement in the aws_iam_policy_document also.